# Insert just key into json without a value

Tags: php, c, json

```
$arr['key1'] = "";
$arr['key2'] = "";
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I get `{"key1":"","key2":""}`. How could I add just a key element without a value? So it would be `{"key1","key2"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output is not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/). If you want to create a list, then use:

```
$arr[0] = 'key1';
$arr[1] = 'key2';
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
["key1","key2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is not correct JSON. An object in JSON uses curly braces, but that means that every key must have a value. You can use a JSON array, which uses square brackets instead.

In other words, you can do:

```
$arr = array( 'key1', 'key2' );`
```

which will produce the json string `'["key1", "key2"]'`, but that's the closest you can get.